# Logcat stopped working on eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat

Logcat gives me this error on eclipse: Could not create the view: For input string: ""In Thread""

Details about the error

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""In Thread""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:514)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogFilter.loadFromString(LogFilter.java:134)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.LogCatView$FilterStorage.getFilterFromStore(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel.createFilters(LogPanel.java:1248)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogPanel.createControl(LogPanel.java:452)
at com.android.ddmuilib.Panel.createPanel(Panel.java:29)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.LogCatView.createPartControl(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:367)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:226)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$ActivationList.setActive(WorkbenchPage.java:4212)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$18.runWithException(WorkbenchPage.java:3271)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3468)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3115)
at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$28.runWithException(Workbench.java:1384)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:134)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3468)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3115)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2316)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
```

Any idea how to fix this.
It seems the problem is in eclipse, since the logcat works fine from the terminal "cmd"

Comment: post the code,specifically the method in which error comes.It is shown in LOgcat

Comment: I'm unable to get the method which causes the error. I've posted above the details of the error non of them refer to a method in my project

Comment: So when does this error occur?

Comment: When I runned one of the classes this happened, and now the logcat is not working for all the projects and for different emulators.

Comment: I have the same problem. It is described absolutely correctly by the author here. Please, don't punish him for your weak knowledge of the problem. It is minimally unfair.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, caused by adding a filter for "MMS:app". `:` in the filter name/settings makes Log Cat in Eclipse fail.

See here for another discussion about this:

[Logcat View fails with "Could not create the view: For input string: "our" "](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ad81d61fc84f6caa/a4f995034d336768?show_docid=a4f995034d336768#)

Copy&Paste of the solution:

> The logcat view crashes after I
>   inserted a filter containing a ":" in 
>   the filtername.  I solved the problem
>   by changing the settings in the file 
>   ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.prefs"
>   placed in the workspace of  eclipse. 
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.logcat.filters=
>   was the key of the fault  setting.

Comment: Fine, but as for me, I have the same error, but not such file or ANY file with ".logcat.filters=" in the computer. I believe that it is a bug connected to filter format. but I CAN'T CHANGE logcat FILTERS!

Comment: Gangnus: Do you find the .metadata-folder in your Eclipse workspace? And the .plugin -folder under that?

I am using Eclipse 3.6.1 under Windows Vista, and the full path is (as the default): C:\Users\username\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\...

The bug will indeed make it so that you can't edit the filters from Eclipse, you must edit the file manually.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, your string must look like "Is Thread". When using quotes in Java you must write them as \" not just ". Change your string to \"Is Thread\".
P.S. If this answer was helpful to you, please consider accepting it. Good luck!